# Pandas df offset using .last

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the line

```
df.last(“1m”)
```

but it starts at the first of this month rather than going back a whole month.
I can’t find the offset to anchor to today.

Comment: Can you add sample to question with expected output?

Comment: So I get results from Dec 1st to yesterday.

Comment: I would like results from Nov 7th to yesterday

Comment: Would going back 28/30/31 *days* instead of a "month" work?

Comment: The problem with that is that the discepency becomes larger for 9M for eg, so 270 days would be off up to 6 days

Comment: you could use `datatime` module to calculate number of days between two dates. It gives you 273-276 days depending on what months you use.

Comment: A gave you a very simple way of doing it, you could obviously expand in complexity. Psuedo code: `if month feb, use 28. if month dec, use 31... etc etc`